# Generic method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an abstract class which has an abstract generic method, which looks something like this

```
protected abstract getData<T>(): T[];
```

Then I have a class which extends this abstract class. Since `getData` is abstract I have to make implementation of it in the child class.

And it looks something like this

```
protected getDataList<T>(): T[] {
    return this.databaseService().getSomethingList();
}
```

`getSomethingList()`returns `Something[]`

I get following error though

> > Type 'Something[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.

I tried few things to resolve this error, but seem to have to make the child implementation generic as well for Typescript to be happy. The above implementation was fine until I upgrade Typescript from `2.2.1` to `2.4.1`.

So I'm wondering how I can make my code compliant again with Typescript 2.4.1?

Comment: A generic method can not return a non-generic field. You either have to make `Something` extend the generic object or change the return type to the object.

Comment: you have getData and getDataList. Is that a typo?  Can you just do this perhaps? protected abstract getData<T[]>(): T[]; protected getData<Something[]>(): Something[] {
    return this.databaseService().getSomethingList();
}

Comment: @JGFMK sry, didn't think of it when I was making the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are trying to set it up so that the entire abstract base is parametrized by a particular type that the derived instance must reify. Here is how you would do that:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
    protected abstract getData(): T[];
}

class Something { }
class SomethingFoo extends Foo<Something> {
    protected getData(): Something[] {
        // implement here
    }
}
```

Note that the function itself isn't parametrized, since the caller of the function isn't the one who gets to decide what type this function will return. Instead, the *containing type* is parametrized, and any derivations of it specify the corresponding type argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation:

```
protected getDataList<T>(): T[] {
    return this.databaseService().getSomethingList();
}
```

Is wrong in that `T` is not substituted in any way. This is called a *useless generic* https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/generics.html

## Fix

```
protected getDataList(): Something[] {
    return this.databaseService().getSomethingList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can define Something[] using some thing like this out of your class:

```
interface Something{
    foo: foo,
    var: var
}
```